# Unable to install features Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-installer

I have a lot of servers that we are unable to install any new features on them.  when we try to install them, we get an error that "The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. The parameter is incorrect. Error 0x8007057"

So far the steps we have taken are:

- Apply Windows Patch KB3041857 - Already installed
- Apply Windows Patch - KB3005628 - Does not apply
- Remove Windows Patch KB2966827 and KB2966828 - Do not exist
- Ran `SFC /scannow` - Nothing returned
- Ran `dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth` - Nothing found
- Tried coping the install ISO Locally and using that as an alternate path - Same issue
- Tried the install via Powershell - Same error message